# Multi-threading on absl.app.run to run yolov4 and tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, tkinter, yolov4

I'm working on a tensorflow yolov4 project, but to end it, I need to display the cv2 image into the tkinter interface.

```py
#Import general library
import time
import datetime as dt

#Import tkinter ui library
import tkinter as tk
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
from threading import Thread, enumerate

#Import yolov4 tensorflow library
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
from absl import app, flags, logging
from absl.flags import FLAGS
import core.utils as utils
from core.yolov4 import filter_boxes
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

#Tensorflow absl.FLAG
flags.DEFINE_string('framework', 'tf', '(tf, tflite, trt')
flags.DEFINE_string('weights', './checkpoints/yolov4-416',
                    'path to weights file')
'''
    more flag.DEFINE_STRING and flag.DEFINE_INTEGER
'''

class UserInterface:
    def __init__(self, window, window_title, vid_width=1280, vid_height=720):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)
    def run():
        self.window.mainloop()
    def update():
        #Bunch of code that update the image inside the gui

def main(_argv):
    config = ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
    STRIDES, ANCHORS, NUM_CLASS, XYSCALE = utils.load_config(FLAGS)
    input_size = FLAGS.size
    video_path = FLAGS.video
    '''
        Reading each FLAGS variable using absl.FLAGS
        Reading video into cv2
    '''
    '''
        Yolov4 loop for each frame of the video,
        - Do some detection task
        - Editing and exporting image
        - Convert image to result(a cv2 image format)
    '''

        if not FLAGS.dis_cv2_window:
            cv2.namedWindow("result", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
            cv2.imshow("result", result)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break
            try:
                ui.update(result)
            except:
                print('No UI')

        if FLAGS.output:
            out.write(result)

        frame_id += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ui = UserInterface(tk.Tk(),"Window title")
        Thread(Target = app.run,args=(main)).start()
        Thread(Target = ui.run, args=())
    
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

My problem here is that I can't run Tkinter on thread because it is a single thread module, which return this error message on run :

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andy\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Andy\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "gui_detectvideo.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.window.title(window_title)
  File "C:\Users\Andy\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2217, in wm_title
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'title', self._w, string)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

But I also don't know how to thread the "app.run(main)" because when I do that, it can't parse the flag variable from the absl library function.

I'm open to all suggestion, thank you

Comment: Please provide a *[minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)* reproducible example. This is a mountain of code. If you're seeing a specific error, please provide the full traceback message.

Comment: @JRiggles thank you for your return, I've already changed question content.
I hope it can be easier for everyone.